# How to prohibit deleting a certain type of element in RecyclerView with a swipe(I want the element not to move)?

Tags: java, android

I have 2 types of items in RecyclerView: Tier = 0 and Row = 1; And I want to delete only "Row"with a swipe. Of course, simply banning is not a problem. And how to remove the possibility of shifting the element on the adapter?

```
ItemTouchHelper helper = new ItemTouchHelper(
            new ItemTouchHandler(0,
                    ItemTouchHelper.LEFT)
    );

    helper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Class itself

```
private class ItemTouchHandler extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {

    public ItemTouchHandler(int dragDirs, int swipeDirs) {
        super(dragDirs, swipeDirs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        int from = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        int to = target.getAdapterPosition();

        Collections.swap(recyclerAdapter.getMoviesList(), from, to);
        recyclerAdapter.notifyItemMoved(from, to);


        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

        recyclerAdapter.deleteRow(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        
    }
```

This is deleting an item in the adapter:

```
public void deleteRow(int position) {

    moviesList.remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case

```
@Override
    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        int dragFlags = 0;
        int swipeFlags = 0;
        if(recyclerAdapter.getMoviesList().get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getType()==Element.TYPE_TIER) {

            swipeFlags = 0;
        } else {
            swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.LEFT;
        }
        return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
    }
```